# Ajax Request status as Canceled

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, ionic-framework

Hi I am calling a ajax request as below to my server from the same server  to store some data while payment process in my ionic app.

```
 //Test code of device
            var formData = {
                payresponseData: response                                
              };
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://app.apiptl.staging.edubold.com/app_dev.php/payment/ajax",
                type: "post",                    
                data: formData,                    
                success: function(data,text) { //alert(data);//return false;                              
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {//return false; 
                alert(request.responseText);alert(request.error);
            }
            }); 
          //Hold window for a while so that ajax will save the data before user hit any other activities while payment flow  
          setTimeout(function(){ window.close() }, 9000);  
         }
```

Before it was working fine , but suddenly its returning status as Canceled every time. I did not find any way to identify the issue, can anyone assist me in this please what went wrong in this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by adding following code in your ajax code:

```
  async: false,
```

Add this code under:

```
$.ajax({
        // Add the code here with other code
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i think its work

```js
function NewDemo(id){
 
 

debugger;
    var formData = {
                payresponseData: id,                                
              };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://app.apiptl.staging.edubold.com/app_dev.php/payment/ajax",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
         success: function(data,text) { //alert(data);//return false;                              
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {//return false; 
                alert(request.responseText);alert(request.error);
            }
            
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ window.close() }, 9000);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="NewDemo(1);">Accept</button>
```

Comment: I fixed it myself, thanks Hardik for your response.  Just used asynch:false  then its works.